# EIGRP Neighbor State

Tags: ospf, eigrp

I understand that OSPF has states that describe the status of a neighbor (e.g. **Init** and **Full**). Does EIGRP also have similar information? I'm programmatically trying to get the status of an EIGRP neighbor using SNMP OIDs. Is there anything in the MIB that can give me the information that I need?

Answer (score 0):

EIGRP isn't nearly as involved as OSPF in establishing neighbor relationships.  Routers discover one another via periodic multicast (and sometimes unicast) hellos.  The hello is answered with an exchange of topology information and the adjacency is formed.  There's not really an equivalent of a DR election, EXSTART, etc..  You can pull information that might indicate a one-way communication (OutQ building up, null SRTT) but it's otherwise pretty on and off.

Apologies if you've already looked at it, but the EIGRP MIB has an EIGRP peer entry - check out 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.449.1.4.1.1 (or browse it @ http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do)